# Trying to run find command from a shell script in one server to another server

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, find, sh

I have a shell script in a server A which has a **find** command to be performed in another server B. How do i do it?

I run my script like this : ./a.sh a.properties

a.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

file="$1"
echo 'Reading file ' $file

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
        echo "Sourcing the file $file"
        . $file
else
        echo "$file not found. Quitting Script"
        exit 1
fi

for serverName in $allServerList
do
        for cleanupPath in $cleanupPathList
        do
                ssh a_io@$serverName -t "find $cleanupPath -type f ! -regex $excludeFileList -mtime -120 -mtime +30 | zip -@ $1/$(date +%Y%m%d).logs.backup.zip"
                ssh a_io@$serverName "find $cleanupPath -type f ! -regex $excludeFileList -mtime +30 -delete"
        done
done
```

a.properties

```
cleanupPathList="/tmp/abc/"
excludeFileList=".*\(.xlsx.*\|.ktr.*\)$"
SERVER1="a"
#SERVER2="b"
allServerList="$SERVER1"
```

But i end up getting the following error
: Name or service not knownname a

Where serverName is my server a

NOTE: *I tried running the same command through command line, then it works.*

Comment: You haven't included enough of your code to tell what is going on. Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code. Include the code that sets the `serverName` variable. And make sure you're showing us an accurate version of the ssh command which you're running and the error message which it's producing. Don't paraphrase these things.

Comment: @Kenster i have edited the question. I cant give the actual server name but the rest of the code is more or less the same

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `serverName` does not exist, or domain in variable not resolving.

If it domain, try resolve it for check IP `host $serverName`

Comment: I tried running the same command through command line, then it works.